# AWS eks has node groups without nodegroups - how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

In the eks cluster, the nodes are added using node groups. I have cluster that has no node groups in the compute section in the eks console but kubectl cluster-info shows the nodes for the cluster. How is this possible?

Comment: How you created the cluster?

Comment: @AmitBaranes - sorry, I have not created the cluster but there are ansible roles and pipelines. But generally, the nodes specific to any cluster should be visible in the compute section, right? correct me if  my understanding is wrong. what are the aws resources that I have to look for to identify how the nodes are attached to the cluster if not added by node groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unmanaged node groups cannot be shown in eks compute section, it can be shown only in master node, when used "eksctl" command